# Обработать ошибки функции, которая удалят папку

Tags: php

Я не понимаю, почему, если удалять папку, которой нету, то мою ошибку не выводит, а выводит Warning: rmdir?

```
try{
            function removeDirectory($dir) {
                if ($objs = glob($dir."/*")) {
                   foreach($objs as $obj) {
                     is_dir($obj) ? removeDirectory($obj) : unlink($obj);
                   }
                }
                rmdir($dir);
            }

            removeDirectory($delFolder);
        }   

        catch (Exception $e) {
            die('Ошибка удаления ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: В случае ошибки rmdir() генерируется ошибка уровня E_WARNING, а не исключение.

Answer (score 1):

```
function removeDirectory($dir) {
    if(!is_dir($dir)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException($dir);
    }
    if ($objs = glob($dir."/*")) {
       foreach($objs as $obj) {
         is_dir($obj) ? removeDirectory($obj) : unlink($obj);
       }
    }
    rmdir($dir);
}
try{
    removeDirectory($delFolder);
} catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    die('Ошибка удаления ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```